# How to accelerate performance work with a lot of conditions in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, coding-style, project

I have a theoretical question. In one project (PHP) from companies, I have a registration form in which various options are selected on the basis of which contracts are proposed to the user.

For example:

If the user selects the "A" option, the script does something.

If the user selects "A" and "B" then the script does something different.

If the user selects "B", "C" and "Q" it does something else. (...) etc

In the script I have all the combinations for each condition listed, but every now and then a new condition appears, for example "Z". Then I have to add more and more code exponentially, which is taking me over 2 hours at the moment.

Do you have any ideas, hints on how to change it, improve something or implement something so as not to write so much code? How do you deal with such projects? I am looking for a semi - automation or acceleration of work :).

I'm sure there's a solution, but I probably don't know it.

Ok, if you need more details, below is the piece of script from a different, simpler part. Can it be improved in some way?

```php
<?php

   (...)
  
    
        
        echo "<td> 
        <center><center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz'> </form> </center>
        </td>";

        echo "<td>
        <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' onclick=\"return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą umowę?')\"> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wynikzug) == 0) {
    
      echo "<td> <center><form action='Start_Formularz_Umowa_Zlecenie_Glovo.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";     
        
        echo "<td> 
        <center><center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz' disabled> </form> </center>
        </td>";

        echo "<td>
        <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' disabled onclick=\"return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą umowę?')\"> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
           
    }
    }
    
     if(mysqli_num_rows($wynik5) == 0) {
       
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'Umowa Zlecenie Glovo'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'Nie mam działalności gospodarczej'."</td>";        
        echo "<td><img src='unchecked1.png'></td>";
        
 echo "<td> <center> <form action='Start_Formularz_Umowa_Zlecenie_Glovo.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj'>
    </form>
    </center>
    </td>";
        
        echo "<td> <center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz' disabled> </form> </center>
       </td>";

    echo "<td>
     <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_zlecenie_glovo'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' disabled> </form> </center>
    </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

        
    }
    
        $wynik3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM example_usermeta where user_id = '$id' and meta_key = 'umowa' and Description='umowa_najmu' "); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wynik3) > 0) { 

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'Umowa Najmu Samochodu'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'Nie mam działalności gospodarczej'."</td>";        
        echo "<td><img src='checked1.png'></td>";
    
        
    $wyniknu = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM example_dokumenty where Login = '$login' and Typ_Umowy='umowa_najmu'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wyniknu) > 0) { 
        
        echo "<td> <center> <form action='Start_formularz_umowa_najem.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";

        echo "<td><center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz'> </form> </center> </td>";

        echo "<td>
        <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' onclick=\"return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą umowę?')\"> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
           
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wyniknu) == 0) {
        
          echo "<td> <center> <form action='Start_formularz_umowa_najem.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";

        echo "<td><center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";

        echo "<td>
        <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' disabled onclick=\"return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą umowę?')\"> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    }
        
    
     if(mysqli_num_rows($wynik3) == 0) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'Umowa Najmu Samochodu'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'Nie mam działalności gospodarczej'."</td>";        
        echo "<td><img src='unchecked1.png'></td>";

        echo "<td><center><form action='Start_formularz_umowa_najem.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj'> </form> </center> </td>";
        
        echo "<td> <center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";
       

        echo "<td>
         <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='umowa_najmu'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' disabled> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";

        
    }
    
    $wynik4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM example_usermeta where user_id = '$id' and meta_key = 'umowa' and Description='oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy' "); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wynik4) > 0) { 
        

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'Oświadczenie Zleceniobiorcy'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'Nie mam działalności gospodarczej'."</td>";        
        echo "<td><img src='checked1.png'></td>";
    
        
    $wynikoz = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID FROM example_dokumenty where Login = '$login' and Typ_Umowy='oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wynikoz) > 0) {
        echo "<td><center> <form action='Start_formularz_oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj' disabled> </form></center> </td>";
        
           echo "<td> <center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz'> </form> </center> </td>";

        echo "<td> 
         <center> <form action='Start_usuwanie_nie_mam.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='deletebutton' value='Usuń' onclick=\"return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą umowę?')\"> </form> </center>
        </td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";

    }
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($wynikoz) == 0) {
          echo "<td><center> <form action='Start_formularz_oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
    <input type='submit' class='generatebutton' value='Generuj' disabled> </form></center> </td>";
        
           echo "<td> <center> <form action='pobierz.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='typ_umowy' value='oświadczenie_zleceniobiorcy'>    
    <input type='hidden' name='login' value='$login'>
    <input type='submit' class='downloadbutton' value='Pobierz' disabled> </form> </center> </td>";

etc etc ...
```

Comment: It really comes down to how much of "something" you can share. If "A" is "buy stocks", and "A and B" is "wash car", then you will just end up writing a lot of code. If "A and B" is "buy stocks then wash car", then you can share the logic. But without knowing more of the specifics, that's about all we can probably tell you.

Comment: Yes, this question is too vague to make any useful suggestions. It's not that we haven't all been there, but there are many possible solutions, and the best choice depends on your exact implementation. My first thought is: You thinking is bases on conditions, what if we could turn this around and base it on the contracts you want to offer?

Comment: I simplified it because it is quite complicated. With the medium-easy option:

If the user selects A, B, and C, the script should display contracts for A B and C, but not display for any others. Additionally, A and B have the same contract, while C has a separate contract only for C and D (D in this contract would have different data, so there would be two the same contracts with different data, but the user didn't choose D, so we're skipping it).

Comment: Then an email is sent to the user confirming the choice (no further action is required, just information about what he should do next and what choice he made) and an email with the contracts (pdf) and information about the user is sent to the owner of the application he chose. Additionally, all data is saved in the database. Also with contracts in pdf files on the server from the contracts that have been generated.

Comment: For me this is still too vague. I am not easily put of by complications, but I need code. I need something I can work with, even if it is, heaven forbid, pseudo code.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, unfortunately still too vague, And as KIKO said, we've all been there, but we need more specifics to really dig in and be helpful. Sometimes you just have to write all of the conditions out in long form before you can find the pattern, too

Comment: Ok, edited the topic with a piece of code :)

Comment: Based only on that code, I would create some helper function such as `createDownloadForm()` that accepts parameters for the dynamic portions, like the login `value`, and whether the button is `disabled`. If possibly, [PHP 8's named arguments](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments) might help making those calls easier to read, too. You aren't going to be able to handle every situation, but it will allow you to take a step back at least.

Comment: I personally find that if I can separate my PHP from my HTML as much as possible, it is way easier to reason about the code in the future. Your HTML will still need dynamic parts, but they aren't "aware" of the rest of your site's logic, they just do their own little thing.

Comment: The code doesn't really look as bad as I had feared, but my Polish isn't so good. I always advice other programmers to write all code in English, because that makes it so much easier to discuss it. Only the text presented to the user needs to be in their language. You seem to repeat code a lot. This is offends against the well known [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). The use of [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and [classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) could help here.

Comment: I can't really comment on the use of conditions here. The logic behind them escapes me.

Comment: Thank you guys for engagement!